# Заполнение структуры

Tags: c++, инициализация, объявление

есть структура:

```
struct Student
{
    char name[N];       // имя
    char surname[N];    // фамилия
    char patronymic[N]; // отчество
    char sex;           // пол
    float year;         // год рождения
    int course;         // курс
};
```

Пытаюсь заполнить:

- Способ 1:

  ```
  Students s[10]={
      { "Иван", "Крузенштерн", "Федерович", 'Ч', 1770, 5 }, //идентификатор Students не определен
      { "Алекс", "Морган", "Андреевич", 'Ч', 1990, 3 },
      { "Элеонора", "Коваленко", "Юрьевна", 'Ж', 1996, 1 },
      { "Петро", "Данилюк", "Степаныч", 'Ч', 1997, 1 },
      { "Сигизмунд", "Варшавский", "Федерович",'Ч', 1987, 3 },
      { "Мирон", "Федоров", "Федерович", 'Ч', 1985, 3 },
      { "Конан", "Варвар", "Бугаевич", 'Ч', 1994, 2 },
      { "Артур", "Менетил", "Андреевич", 'Ч', 1820, 5 },
      { "Тирион", "Ланнистер", "Федерович", 'Ч', 1974, 4 },
      { "Андрей", "Штальдер", "Данилович", 'Ч', 1870, 5 }};
  ```
- Способ 2:

  ```
  Student s[10];
  s[0] = { "Иван", "Крузенштерн", "Федерович", 'Ч', 1770, 5 };    //требуется выражение
  s[1] = { "Алекс", "Морган", "Андреевич", 'Ч', 1990, 3 };        //требуется выражение
  s[2] = { "Элеонора", "Коваленко", "Юрьевна", 'Ж', 1996, 1 };    //требуется выражение
  s[3] = { "Петро", "Данилюк", "Степаныч", 'Ч', 1997, 1 };        //требуется выражение
  s[4] = { "Сигизмунд", "Варшавский", "Федерович",'Ч', 1987, 3 }; //требуется выражение
  s[5] = { "Мирон", "Федоров", "Федерович", 'Ч', 1985, 3 };       //требуется выражение
  s[6] = { "Конан", "Варвар", "Бугаевич", 'Ч', 1994, 2 };         //требуется выражение
  s[7] = { "Артур", "Менетил", "Андреевич", 'Ч', 1820, 5 };       //требуется выражение
  s[8] = { "Тирион", "Ланнистер", "Федерович", 'Ч', 1974, 4 };    //требуется выражение
  s[9] = { "Андрей", "Штальдер", "Данилович", 'Ч', 1870, 5 };     //требуется выражение
  ```

Ни тем, ни тем способом не получается. Помогите исправить.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Чему равно значение N?

Comment: @aredBay Сообщение об ошибке достаточно ясное. Имя структуры  Student, а не Students.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сообщение об ошибке достаточно ясное. Имя структуры `Student`, а не `Students`. Используйте правильное имя.

```
Student s[10]={{ "Иван", "Крузенштерн", "Федерович", 'Ч', 1770, 5 },
^^^^^^^
//...
```

Comment: Бож, спасибо. Пора спать...

Answer (score 3):

Ну, а если вдруг захочется через присваивание - то

```
Student s[10];
s[0] = Student{ "Иван", "Крузенштерн", "Федерович", 'Ч', 1770, 5 };
```